# With higher-order functions in Kotlin, why are lambdas shown outside of other function parameters?

Tags: java, function, kotlin, lambda

In some training I'm reviewing, I don't understand exactly how an example higher-order function and lambda are connected through syntax

This higher-order Kotlin function

```
fun myWith(name: String, block: String.() -> Unit) {
  name.block()
}
```

Is invoked like this

```
myWith(fish.name) {
  capitalize()
}
```

I understand the second part is a lambda but I don't understand why it's not included as a second parameter to the function and just hung outside of the parameters. Like why is it not invoked as:

```
myWith(fish.name, { capitalize() } )
```

Later a more verbose description of the example is shown as

```
myWith(fish.name, object : Function1<String, Unit> {
  override fun invoke(name: String) {
    name.capitalize()
  }
})
```

Which IS including the lambda inside the normal list of parameters to `myWith`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter of a function accepts a function, a lambda expression that is passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses.

Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter

Comment: Ugh, OK. Seems arbitrary and inconsistent, but I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: That link doesn't explain *why* it's allowed, which is AIUI to allow higher-order function calls that look like language syntax.  For example, `repeat (10) { /*...*/ }` looks comparable to a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: @gidds In fact, this is described just a few lines down: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ, but I don't think the example there provides as strong an example as mine :-)

Comment: @GenerationTech This is a common pre-existing idiom adopted from languages such as Ruby and Groovy.